# Displaying a div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make my Website more accessible to users that don't have javascript.

Content that will be visible if the user has JavaScript Enabled 
 


Content visible when Java Script is not running

By default DisableJS is set to `Display:none;`

I have an external javascript file with the following line

`$(".DisableJS ").css("Display", "inline");`

Is the javaScript code i'm using wrong ( is it all that I need to do this) , if so how can I fix this?

Comment: That should work fine. Note you can just do `$(".DisableJS ").show();`

Comment: Have a look at [<noscript>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but try `"display"` attribute with lowercase instead of `"Display"`, and remove space after `DisableJS` in `$(".DisableJS ")` :

```
$(".DisableJS").css("display", "inline");
```